# How to import Android AAR dependencies using Maven in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, android-maven-plugin

Note : I am using Maven 3.2.2, Eclipse Luna

This is the dependency in my pom.xml that uses Android AAR archive

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.gabrielemariotti.cards</groupId>
    <artifactId>library</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.3</version>
    <type>aar</type>
</dependency>
```

I can see the classes installed in target/classes folder.

But when I try to use the classes in the AAR, Eclipse is showing class cannot be resolved. I have no problem using classes added by JAR dependencies in pom.xml

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you edited the `pom.xml` file outside Eclipse? If yes, have you already tried with a Project -> Clean... ?

Comment: Yes I have tried Project -> Clean

Comment: Just to have some more clues: _1._ are you using M2E? _2._ Can you see the AAR in Package Explorer -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Maven Dependencies? _3._ When you say "Eclipse is showing class cannot be resolved" you mean that the auto-completion doesn't show your class?

Comment: @marcello Yes, I am using M2E, the AAR does not appear in the Maven Dependecies, yes, I mean that eclipse auto-completion does not show the class to import.

I also checked out the my maven local repository at ~/.m2. It has the AAR installed in ~/.m2/repository/com/github/gabrielemariotti/cards/library/1.7.3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At this present moment in time the [m2e-android plug-in](http://rgladwell.github.io/m2e-android/) cannot support AAR files because the ADT development team [have not added AAR support to the Eclipse ADT plug-in](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=59183).

This is an outstanding issue:

https://github.com/rgladwell/m2e-android/issues/177

Comment: Thanks for the info. This is a good plug-in.  Hoping that support for AAR could be added ASAP.  =)

Comment: They were suppose to add this years ago... so I guess they wont :(

Comment: Who do you mean by "they"?

Comment: Man are they ever going to fix this?

Comment: I'm also facing the same problem.. Trying to use AAR in Eclipse. Since I'm familiar with the @RicardoGladwell answer in the link above I didn't expect it to work in Eclipse.. However I aslo see that the project is not build by Maven (using mvn clean install). I see errors like "cannot find symbol". I thought that mvn would work since Maven Android Plugin officially support aar. http://simpligility.github.io/android-maven-plugin/aar.html

Answer (score 0):

After doing some online research, it seems there is no easy and straightforward way to do this. AAR is not a standard format and not supported by Eclipse. It will take a hack in order to get this to work. Here are three options with various levels of experience:

- The Android SDK comes with the source to standard Android libraries in `$ANDROID_HOME/extras/android/support`. (Alternatively, if you can grab the source of whatever third-party library you’re using, that should work as well.) Import that library into your workspace as a separate project and set its properties to identify it as an Android library. Then, in the Android section of your project’s properties, add a library reference. This won’t take any effect outside of Eclipse (e.g. it won’t affect a Maven command-line build), but it will allow Eclipse to resolve references to that library. I’ve done that successfully for some v7 support libraries.
- An AAR is essentially a zip file containing a `classes.jar` and a bunch of Android-specific resources, all of whic appear to be in a format that Eclipse can work with. If you’ve built agains that library at least once, grab it from your M2 cache (`~/.m2/repository`). Unpack the AAR into a directory of your choice (you will need to keep it around for as long as you are planning to build against that library). Add the `classes.jar` to your project’s classpath. This should let Eclipse resolve any Java references, but not Android-specific references (such as styles).
- Combining the two approaches above, you can also try importing the unzipped AAR as a project and adding that to your project. This should allow Eclipse to resolve not only Java references but also Android-specific ones. You will need to experiment a bit with that one, as the project will have no Java sources but instead a JAR which needs to be included in the build path.

Answer (score -1):

You can try my Maven plugin https://bitbucket.org/komo81/eclipse-aar-maven-plugin.

Plugin generates Eclipse projects for Android AAR dependencies to easy import in Eclipse. It works together with https://github.com/simpligility/android-maven-plugin, which unpacks Android AAR dependencies into /target/unpacked-libs directory. This plugin takes these unpacked dependencies and modifies them to easy import in Eclipse for ADT plugin. So plugin makes following changes during 'generate' goal execution:

- copies AAR project directories from input directory to output directory
- moves /classes.jar to /libs/project_name.jar
- moves /jni directory to /libs
- creates .project, .classpath, .settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs and project.properties files
- creates /gen directory
- add references to root project.properties file

**Usage**

Add plugin to your pom.xml

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.bitbucket.komo81</groupId>
      <artifactId>eclipse-aar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>clean</goal>
            <goal>generate</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>dropbox</id>
        <url>https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/52711537/maven-repo/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Run `mvn compile`. Import generated projects from /eclipse-aar directory into Eclipse via 'Import -> Existing projects into Workspace'.

**Plugin goals documentation**

http://komo81.bitbucket.org/eclipse-aar-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html

Comment: Generally, links to a tool or library [should be accompanied by usage notes, a specific explanation of how the linked resource is applicable to the problem, or some sample code](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605), or if possible all of the above.

Comment: This plugin is outdated: 
[ERROR] Plugin org.bitbucket.komo81:eclipse-aar-maven-plugin:1.0.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.bitbucket.komo81:eclipse-aar-maven-plugin:jar:1.0.0 in central (http://jcenter.bintray.com)

Comment: Plugin is not outdated, you have to add section <pluginRepositories> to your pom.xml as described.

Comment: It is not working as the dropbox URL no loger seems to exist. I filed an issue for this. Furhter I have cloned and compiled the plugin myself - had to fix the build for recent JDK. Now, I can use the plugin but it does not seem to work. Here is my resume about android development:
https://github.com/m-m-m/ui-android/wiki/android-sucks

Comment: Hello, sorry but this plugin is no longer maintainted.