# Create Android Archive Library(AAR) with maven only

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, android-library, aar

I am developing a library project which I would like to distribute to other developers.

There have been many discussions on this topic on internet, people suggested to create a distribute version library project which contains only my library project's jar & other resources. It sounds good.

Then, I suddenly found there are people suggested to create Android Archive Library (AAR). But they all uses a tool named Gradle

I am using Eclipse with Maven for my Android library project. My question is, is it possible to generate AAR achieve for my android library project  **without using Gradle** but only with Maven? If so, how?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to resolve class import from from Android AAR typed dependecy using Maven?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24702508/how-to-resolve-class-import-from-from-android-aar-typed-dependecy-using-maven)

Comment: I disagree with dupe suggestion. That is specifically about Eclipse and thus has no answer. This question has a great answer below that worked for me.

Answer (score 10):

The android-maven-plugin allows to package a project as aar-file.

From their documentation http://simpligility.github.io/android-maven-plugin/:

> ## Produce an AAR
>
> If you have a bunch of Java code that you want to share then the best solution is to create a Java project and publish as a plain Java archive (ie jar).
>
> But if you have code plus Android resources that you want to share then you really want to share that as an Android archive (ie AAR). Fortunately this is easy.
>
> Just add configure your project to have packaging aar (and add the android-maven-plugin to build/plugins section of your maven project). Eg

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycoolcompany</groupId>
  <artifactId>general-lib</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>aar</packaging>

  ...
</project>
```

Comment: The linked GitHub project seems to be outdated. Any modern idea ?