# Does eclipse photon has problems dealing with aar ? eclipse generally ? how to deal with it?

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, gradle, aar

I quite a newbie in android.

I use Eclipse Photon (4.8.0.I20180611-0500) with following plugins :

- Android Development Tools (23.0.7.2120684)
- Android for Maven Eclipse (1.4.0)

I cloned https://github.com/simpligility/android-maven-plugin.

Then I use eclipse to open example android projects, such as **libraryprojects** project and its subproject.

**libraryprojects** is a set of simple maven project for android. It just show how to create and use libraries with android-maven-plugin.

When I build libraryprojects from command line, everything work (excepts test project) :

```
cd libraryprojects
mvn clean install
```

**However, in eclipse, there are some problems, or I am having difficulties making code working well :**

- first, we have to create a default.properties or project.properties file at each android project root to be able to add "android project nature".
- second, and I'm stuck on this : "cannot be resolved to a type" eclipse errors for all projects which have AAR type dependencies.
- thirst, we have to make symbolic link for AndroidManifest.xml and res folder to get them accessible from each android project root folder.

I tried to understand how to solve it, read some article and forums on google like this one :
[How to import Android AAR dependencies using Maven in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24702508/how-to-import-android-aar-dependencies-using-maven-in-eclipse)

However, this article is old and the proposed solutions are workarounds. And they are old, so I'd like to know :

- if I make some mistakes
- if eclipse will not work with aar libs
- if I'd better use Android Studio (or Intellij) for android projects ...

I also see this interesting post to convert gradle project to eclipse or idea projects : 
[How to use Gradle to generate Eclipse and Intellij project files for Android projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17470831/how-to-use-gradle-to-generate-eclipse-and-intellij-project-files-for-android-pro/17608728#17608728), but I really don't know if I must continue with it, or if another method is easiest.

**Can some one help me dealing with this ?**

Notice : when using other android projects built with gradle, the problems stay the same : unresolved symbol when using classes from AAR.

For example, when I try to use these AAR dependencies, gradle build is ok but Eclipse tells me that used classes of this jars cannot be resolved.
  - com.github.sahasbhop:formatted-log:0.0.5'
  - com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.4

Comment: If you are new to Android and not tied to Eclipse strongly, the general recommendation is to use Android Studio (AS)  as it is an official Google product. Given that the majority of Android developers use AS you are more likely to find solutions for problems encountered.

Comment: Eclipse has not been supported for Android development for a long time now.

Comment: Thank you for your time and your answers. I liked the idea that eclipse could aims to support quite all programmation langage ... And I was thinking that ADT eclipse plugin was pretty recent (I don't know last release date in fact ...)   So, as you both suggest, I will try to install AS and use it ...